# how to validate phone number in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validation a text box for phone number.
It should accept phone numbers of all countries.

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Letters only");

(function($,W,D)
{

    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                     phoneno:{
                              required:true,  
                              regx:/^(?![8]{10}|[9]{10})[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/,
                            minlength:10,
                            maxlength:14,
                        }
},
messages: {
{
                            required:"<font color='red'>Phone number is Required</font>",
                           regx:"<font color='red'>Enter only Numbers</font>",
                           minlength:"<font color='red'>Minimum length is 10 </font>",
                          maxlength:"<font color='red'>Maximum length is 14 </font>",
                    }
  },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();


    });

})(jQuery, window, document);

</script>
<input id="phoneno" type="text" placeholder="phone no..." class="form-control input-small" value="" name="phoneno">
```

Comment: Different countries have different lengths of phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" class="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

     $.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid phone number");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                field1: 'customphone'
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s82em3wx/1/

This accepts

+91xxxxxxxxxx

+91-xxxxxxxxxx

0xxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Hey can you include your references and a bit more information about how it works :)

Comment: and i want mobile number format like this
+918801234567
+960059114811

not valid formats
+890765+312

Answer (score 0):

you can see this demo

```
function validatePhone(txtPhone) {
        var a = document.getElementById(txtPhone).value;
        var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
        if (filter.test(a)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }​



$('#txtPhone').blur(function(e) {
   if (validatePhone('txtPhone')) {
       $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Valid');
       $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
   }
   else {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Invalid');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
   }
});
```